# Правильно ли говорить «находиться в отпуске»?

Tags: этимология, стилистика

Кажется, что глагол «находиться» скорее про место, а отпуск - это временной промежуток или состояние.

Comment: Находиться это одно из значений глагола был. У вас же не вызывает вопросов: Он был в отпуске, Он был в командировке, Он был в загуле

Answer (score 2):

*...отпуск — это временной промежуток или состояние.*

Ну да, совершенно верно.
В толковом словаре Дмитриева:
[находи́ться](https://gufo.me/dict/dmitriev/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)
**3.** Если кто-либо или что-либо находится в каком-либо положении, состоянии, значит, кто-либо или что-либо пребывает в таком положении, состоянии. *Мы с ним находимся в дружеских отношениях.* | *Рынок находится в состоянии неустойчивого равновесия.*

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
*Самсонов, который в момент объявления войны **находился в отпуске**, в Ташкент не вернулся...* (А. А. Татищев. Земли и люди: В гуще переселенческого движения (1906-1921) (1928));
*К началу войны примерно половина дипломатического состава **находилась в отпуске*** (Валентин Бережков. Рядом со Сталиным (1971-1998));
*С четой Русеевых, которые **находятся в отпуске** и ждут самолета на Якутск, почти весь день провел в районе аэродрома* (Б. И. Вронский. Дневник (1952));
*Растянувшись на горячем песке и подставив спину обжигающим солнечным лучам, я впал в ленивую дремоту, думая о том, как хорошо все-таки **находиться в отпуске**, и даже не подозревая, что отпуск мой уже закончился* (Александра Маринина. Черный список (1995)).

Answer (score 1):

Находится в состоянии алкогольного опьянения, находится в подпитии. "находиться в числе военачальников" 1700 год Григорий Сковорода.  И кстати, что такое "место", почему именно "в месте", с чего вы так решили? Находиться в точке старта, точка место? Находиться в точке - вообще ничего не значащая фраза. Находиться на старте, находиться в моменте. Находиться в - это про время, состояние и прочую абстракцию: находиться в столе - внутри стола, не на месте, не в месте, а в понятии места. Находится в Москве. Москва - не место, Москва - город. Вообще интересно.

А что же такое место? Кладбище - это место, даже места захоронения. Находиться в кладбище - ну бред) Находиться в могиле - очень расплывчато, если бы кто-то находился внутри могилы-места, сказали бы "закопан в могиле", труп находится в могиле - тоже не говорят, труп зарыт в могиле, хотя даже без в могиле - труп зарыт или даже труп в земле.

Вообще у меня вызывает сложность поиска места, без понятия - кроме в-на могиле/могилу придумать не могу. Потому что понятие - это как раз "в месте" - внутри чего-то. Понимание - это же понимание сути чего-то, то есть такое какое оно есть внутри, а не такое как это выглядит снаружи. Место - это на месте, быть не месте, находится на месте - находится на отпуске, так тоже говорят. А в месте - не говорят без дополнения, в месте чего? "вместе" тут и есть то, что наменяет "внутри" или "понятие".

Кстати вот есть слово шкаф - это скорее место. В шкафу - очень специфичное слово, потому что раньше могли сказать в шкапе, но редко. А вообще говорили обычно в сундукЕ, в буфетЕ. И даже на буфетЕ и на сундукЕ.

Потому что это тоже вроде как понятия. Однако, со шкафом как-то не получилось, почему?

То есть что такое место вообще? Место - это куда можно дойти. То есть место - это связка с глаголом, а не с понятием. Бредить - в бреду, шкаф - от глагола schaffen — «делать, создавать», - в шкафу - создавать место для посуды. А буфет - это понятие и предмет, созданное для посуды.

Взять на руку, взять на руке не скажешь. Но сидеть на руке, а не сидеть на руку. Взять - это я беру, активное действие. А сидеть - это пассивное. То есть находиться в состоянии сидения, понятие, наречие - сидя. А беря - очень не наречие, а деепричастие, которое сразу скатывается в идиому - беря за руку. То есть нельзя находиться в состоянии "беря".

То есть, что в итоге):

В - это предлог скорее понятия, чем места.

Место - это поверхность, а не то, что внутри, то что внутри - это понятие.

Место - это указание куда, к чему, для глагола действия, к чему применять действие. Место может быть выражено глаголом преобразованным в деепричастие.

Понятие - это указание о нахождении в каком-то состоянии, глагол может быть преобразован в наречие.

Место сочетается с окончанием на -У или в -У.

А понятие сочетается с окончанием на -Е или в -Е.

Из "отпуск" можно сделать место, но тогда получится в/на ОТПУСКУ. Так тоже говорят, но реже, хотя изначально было "в отпуску", хотя это как "в шкапе", хотя в шкапе реже говорили. Возможно, это связано с тем, что отпуск - это отпускать, глагол всё же, отглагольное понятие.

> Имея уже в кармане свой билет для выезда (не столько по болезни, сколько из любознательности) за границу, а следственно, уже считаясь по службе **в отпуску**... Достоевский.

В отпуску - упоминаний примерно в 2 раза меньше, чем в отпуске.

Answer (score 0):

**ПРАВИЛЬНО.**

Вот миллион примеров употребления словосочетания "находиться в отпуске".

https://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B2+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5%22&num=10

Вот примеры из "вычитанных" текстов советской эпохи с фильтром с 1920 по 1991 год.

https://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B2+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min:1+%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B2.+1920%E2%80%AF%D0%B3.,cd_max:31+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA.+1990%E2%80%AF%D0%B3.&num=10

Comment: Ссылки на некий источник (не аргументы!) ответом быть не могут.

Comment: Cсылки на жизнь и частотность употребления синтаксических конструкций в текстах на русском языке ответом быть могут. Google Books - одна из крупнейших баз текстов на русском языке. Статистика употребления словосочетания  - ярчайшее свидетельство его легитимности и "правильности".

Comment: Из «Справок и прочих ресурсов» сайта: **Как ссылаться на материалы, написанные другими**

Если вы нашли полезный ресурс, который может помочь в решении вопроса (на другом сайте или в ответе на Русский язык), убедитесь, что вы выполнили все следующие пункты:

    предоставьте ссылку на исходную страницу или **ответ**;
    **процитируйте только относящийся к вопросу отрывок**;
    укажите имя автора исходного текста (выделение слов моё).

Comment: Я ссылку предоставил, название текстов и имена авторов там указаны, цитировать сотни примеров употребления здесь я не собираюсь.

Comment: Что же тогда ПРАВИЛЬНО? Вы не ответ дали, а только совет типа: пишите также, как наши деды писали (и нам завещали), и не заморачивайтесь промежутками и состоянием. Ссылки можно в окошке *Добавить комментарий* оставить, там им место.

Comment: Базы текстов - это представительная выборка, это фактический типологический материал для исследования и статистики.

Это не ваши личные домыслы о том, как что-то писать, а объективная реальность, показывающая, что данное словосочетание фактически именно в такой форме живёт в устах и письме сотен и тысяч людей. 

Что касается промежутков и состояний, то в базе собраны тексты разных эпох : от 18 века до современных. Данная мною выборка показывает, что словосочетание "находиться в отпуске" существовало и сто лет назад и существует в современном русском языке, в прозе 2022 года.

Comment: И вообще, я сам выбираю тип ответа, тип аргумента и тип доказательства чего-либо, а если вы его не понимаете или оно вам не нравится, то это ваши проблемы.

Comment: Познакомьтесь с сайтом, со своим-то самоваром в Тулу не ездят.

Comment: Я с сайтом знаком пять лет, так что не учите меня.